# Don't repeat a piece of code in a jQuery snippet

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code that works nice (is uses [TypeWatch plugin](https://github.com/dennyferra/TypeWatch)):

```
$( "#Codice" ).typeWatch({
    callback: function(value){
        $.post("../ajax/key.php", {
            Codice: value,
            ID: $( "#ID" ).val()
            },
            function(data){
                $( "#availability" ).html(data);
            }
        );
    },
    wait: 500,
    captureLength: 1
}).keypress(function(){
    $( "#availability" ).html('');
});
```

But, following a DRY approach, I'd like to avoid the double `$( "#availability" )` repetition. I tried several things but none of them works: have you got an idea for this, please?

Thanks

Comment: assign `$( "#availability" )` to a variable in a shared scope then use it in both the places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite right to do so, much better in terms of performance too.

Store it in a variable and use that.

```
var $availability = $("#availability");
$("#Codice").typeWatch({
    callback: function(value){
        $.post("../ajax/key.php", {
            Codice: value,
            ID: $( "#ID" ).val()
            },
            function(data){
                $availability.html(data);
            }
        );
    },
    wait: 500,
    captureLength: 1
}).keypress(function(){
    $availability.html('');
});
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! Just a further question: can I use 'var availability' insstead of 'var $availability'? Are there differences?

Comment: @Ivan You can use whatever you like for the variable name. Just out of convention I always prepend jQuery objects stored in variables with `$` to differentiate them from non-jquery objects.